# Does OCaml have C-like round() and trunc() functions?

Tags: floating-point, ocaml

OCaml's standard library includes several floating-point functions equivalent to C ones, such as `mod_float` for C's `fmod()`, the exponentiation operator `**` for C's `pow()`, and other functions such as `ceil`, `log`, etc.

But does it also include equivalents for `round()` and `trunc()`? There is `truncate`/`int_of_float`, but their type is `float -> int` and not `float -> float`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It contains the `modf` function, that is a swiss-knife function, with which you can define the `truncatef` and `roundf` functions:

```
# let truncatef x = snd (modf x);;
val truncatef : float -> float = <fun>
# truncatef 3.14;;
 - : float = 3.
```

The `round` function also can be expressed with `modf`

```
# let roundf x = snd (modf (x +. copysign 0.5 x));;
val roundf : float -> float = <fun>
# roundf 3.14;;
- : float = 3.
# roundf 3.54;;
- : float = 4.
# roundf (~-.3.54);;
- : float = -4.
```

However it can be expressed more succinctly (and efficiently) with `floor`

```
# let roundf x = floor (x +. 0.5)
```

But both rounding functions are a little bit buggy, as comment in `core`'s implementation states:

```
(* Outside of the range [round_nearest_lb..round_nearest_ub], all representable doubles
   are integers in the mathematical sense, and [round_nearest] should be identity.

   However, for odd numbers with the absolute value between 2**52 and 2**53, the formula
   [round_nearest x = floor (x + 0.5)] does not hold:

   # let naive_round_nearest x = floor (x +. 0.5);;
   # let x = 2. ** 52. +. 1.;;
   val x : float = 4503599627370497.
   # naive_round_nearest x;;
   - :     float = 4503599627370498.
*)
let round_nearest_lb = -.(2. ** 52.)
let round_nearest_ub =    2. ** 52.
```

So a little bit more correct way to implement the rounding would be (from Core library):

```
let round_nearest t =
  if t >= round_nearest_lb && t <= round_nearest_ub then
    floor (t +. 0.5)
  else
    t
```

But even this `round_nearest` is not flawless, for example:

```
# round_nearest 0.49999999999999994;;
- : float = 1.
```

This `0.49999999999999994` is an immediate predecessor of `0.5`. Pascal's [blog](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1) contains suggestions on how to solve this issue. The following should work in OCaml:

```
let round_nearest t =
  if t >= round_nearest_lb && t <= round_nearest_ub then
    floor (t +. 0.49999999999999994)
  else
    t

# round_nearest 0.49999999999999994;;
- : float = 0.
# round_nearest (~-.0.49999999999999994);;
- : float = 0.
# round_nearest (~-.1.49999999999999994);;
- : float = -1.
# round_nearest 0.5;;
- : float = 1.
# round_nearest ~-.0.5;;
- : float = -1.
#
```

And this is only one rounding policy, round to nearest (the intuitive one). There are other policies, that have their own caveats.

Comment: That's truncate, not round.

Comment: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/02/nearbyintf1 shows one more value for which Core's tests are not enough: the predecessor of `0.5`.

Answer (score 4):

The `Core` library has a [Float](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/blob/master/src/float_intf.ml) module with many such functions.

Comment: For others finding this answer at this point, the link to Core's Float module documentation is currently broken.  Core and its documentation is in flux, but at present, [this page](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core/Std/Float_intf.mod/S.modt/) is one of those that shows the extensive collection of rounding functions that it provides.

Answer (score 1):

For truncate, someone gave you an answer already:

```
let truncatef x = snd (modf x);
```

For round, I suggest:
`BatFloat.round_to_int` or `BatFloat.round`

Check [this](https://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatFloat.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function truncate having the type `float -> float`, you can do this but it is very ugly :

```
let mytruncate x = float_of_int (truncate x)
```

Comment: That won't work if the number is outside of the int range though.

Comment: Indeed, from some tests in my machine, `truncate` cannot go higher than 2^61 (and can even output negative values in some cases), returning 0 for higher values since they are outside its specified range. While a "true" `trunc` function should work even for these values.